# Misunderstanding geometric series of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, power-series

$A$ is a $3$ by $3$ real matrix, $rank(A) = 2$, $\lambda_{max}(I_3 - A) < 1$. I am interested in the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(I_3 - A)^k$.

Going through the usual proof, we have $\displaystyle S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(I_3-A)^k$, multiply by $(I_3 - A)$ on the right to get $S_n(I_3 - A) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(I_3-A)^{k+1}$, subtract them to get $S_n(I_3 - (I_3-A)) = S_nA=I_3 -(I_3-A)^{n+1}$.

Similarly if we would have multiplied on the left, we would have gotten $AS_n = I_3-(I_3-A)^{n+1}$

Looking at the limit, since $\lim_{n \to \infty}I_3-(I_3-A)^{n+1} = I_3$, then $A$ and $S_\infty$ are inverses of each other.

How does this sit with the fact $rank(A) = 2$ but $A$ is 3 by 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rank of $A$ is $2$, then the nullspace of $A$ is non-trivial and there must be an eigenvector $v$ of $A$ with eigenvalue $0$.
Thus $(I-A)v=v$, so the largest eigenvalue of $I-A$ would not be less than $1$. The two statements are contradictory.